# How to screen mirror to a Smart TV

Tags: screen, tv, smart

How I can screen mirror to a smart tv like a android device?
I don't want to use any type of video cable.

Answer (score 1):

On your TV, you need specialised hardware to do this to turn your TV into a "projector" that just "projects" on its own screen.

For an android device, it depends on the device (whether or not it has any display input ports) and then you use the same technology as above.

Comment: My TV supports the screen mirroring option, because i tested it on a windows 8.1 tablet